# Do I need a 404 for a onepage site?

Tags: html, server, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

Should I create a 404 page for one page websites, or can I just redirect the 404 error to the one and only home page?

What is the best practice? Etc.

Comment: I actually tend to redirect the 404 errors to the home.

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:seo] tag, questions asking what is best for search engines are not on-topic here.

Comment: Took away SEO question because it's only one of the factors, but it seems that people focus on that.

Answer (score -1):

If the link is not correct, a web page is sent with a 404, which can be divided into two cases

### 1- Redirection

It is specified in the html code that it will be redirected and after 2 (it can be in a different time) seconds it is redirected to the homepage

### 2- 404 Page

The html code will show a page telling you that you came to a wrong place, for example if you try to open a repo that is not on github, it will not redirect you to the homepage, it will tell you that the repo cannot be found. optionally you can go to the homepage from the navbar.

###### In terms of SEO, it is a very bad practice for SEO not to send any data on bad links. so I recommend you to apply one of the 2 methods above.